# Is there a race condition between an update trigger and multiple commits in a transaction, using an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, triggers, transactions, race-condition

A sequence of several commits occur within a single transaction. In the first commit a row is created in a table A. In the other commits rows are created in joined tables B and C.

An update trigger exists on table A. The trigger code requires data from the joined tables B and C.

I expect/presume that after the first commit, the update trigger will run and try to access the data in tables B and C.

Am I correct in thinking there will be a race condition between the trigger running and the completion of the rest of the commits in the transaction?

Currently in testing the trigger completes without exception, but perhaps there will be intermittent failures?

Comment: First, a transaction by definition can only have one commit. So if you have multiple commits, you have multiple transactions. Second, if the trigger is an update trigger, it wouldn't fire when you create a row (insert), only when you update one. So, as long as you have already inserted the child records in B and C in the same session (whether committed or not, it doesn't matter), you can subsequently do an update of A and that trigger would be able to see what it needs to in B and C. If this doesn't answer your question please provide some code or at least pseudo code to clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after seeing your comment about a transaction only having one commit, I can see our database framework, Dapper is only committing once at the end of the sequence. It was my misunderstanding; I thought the individual Execute( commands were commits. So therefore no race-condition would exist.